# Segmentation of a line based on several overlapping lines within the first line

Tags: topology, linestring, linear-referencing

I stumbled over a problem which I can't figure out myself so maybe you can help me..

I have a line going from 0 to 100% of its length. On this line I have 1:n lines with different information and they differ in its length (e.g. one from 20 to 80%; one 35-50% and so on). What I want is a segmentation of the line containing the information of each of the "sub"-lines. In the example I would get 5 segmentations. (0 - 20 - 35 - 50 - 80 - 100). I have also the start and end percentage of each line (if this helps in any way).

example data (.shp) is [here](https://drive.cnv.at/index.php/s/J16msRzTR7KfOdF)

Comment: Specify in what software you work, for example QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc.

Comment: I work with ArcGis, QGIS and PostGIS, I don‘t mind which software will solve the problem..

Comment: the link will be useful to you http://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineSubstring.html

Comment: Note that the function works only with LINESTRING, that is, first convert MULTILINESTRING to LINESTRING, using the ST_LineMerge function...